# How to test player movement speed in 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am wondering if there is a better way to track, or test, how fast a player is going, then activate command off that. So far I have: `/scoreboard objective add Sprint stat.WalkOneCm` Then, every tick I have that set to zero. `/scoreboard players set @p Sprint 0` Then, after it resets 5 times, It tests to see if the players movement speed if in between **150 and 200 WalkOneCm score per tick.** If true, then you get a speed boost. However, sometimes it fails, and tests when its at 50 or so. Is there a better measurement?

Comment: Are you using 1.8 or 1.9 version of Minecraft?

Comment: How are you doing your test?  That seems to be the important part.

Comment: I am using 1.8 Jason_
@MBraedley I am using a testfor command **/testfor @p[score_Sprint=200,score_Sprint_min=150]** and that activates every 5 ticks. Each reset is 1 tick

Comment: also, I have no idea how to highlight test, only bold and italic it. sorry about that, I would highlight commands if I knew how.

Comment: With the editor just push the button that looks like two brackets { } and it will format your code nicely for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible answer, but I haven't got it to work yet:

First, you build a clock (with a bit longer delay).

Then, you let a set of Command blocks be triggered at once. Theese CMD blocks should summon a circle of Armour Stands **with different names** around the Player.
Then, after a small delay, a CMD Block row tests the Player distance from each ArmorStand (by name). If any Player-ArmorStand distance is smaller then, let's say, 1 block, another command is executed, eg.:

> /execute @e[name=ArmorStand1] ~ ~ ~ execute @a[r=1] say @p is sprinting

If summoned in this way, it gives a total of 24 CMD blocks:

> _ ■ ■ ■ _
>   ■ _ _ _ ■
>   ■ _ P _ ■
>   ■ _ _ _ ■
>    _ ■ ■ ■ _

P for Player, ■ for ArmorStand, _ for nothing.